# Dividing n different balls to r different with max p balls in a cell where the way the balls are sorted in each cell is important

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the number of ways to divide n different ball to r different cells when:
>
> 1. No cell may contain more than p balls.
> 2. The internal order in  each cell is important.

I thought about using the inclusion-exclusion principle to solve the problem, however I have two questions:

1. Is my solution correct?
2. Is there a simpler approach?

The solution:

The number of ways to divide n different ball to r different cells with no limitations is:

$$\frac{(n+r-1)!}{(r-1)!}$$
So $W(0)$=$\frac{(n+r-1)!}{(r-1)!}$

We will define $A_i$ to be the number of ways to divide the balls where the $i$ cell has more than $p$ balls in it.

Using this definition, $A_i=\frac{n!}{(n-p-1)!}*\frac{(n-p-1+r-1)!}{(r-1)!}$ (We choose $p+1$ balls, and then can divide the remaining $n-p-1$ balls which way we wish).

Using this method, I get:
$$W(k)={r\choose k}*\frac{n!}{(n-k(p+1))!}*\frac{(n-k(p+1)+r-1)!}{(r-1)!}$$

And the final answer will be: $$E(0)=\sum_{k=0}^{r} (-1)^k*W(k) $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, I do not think there is any simpler way.